# How to build Security Token Service (STS) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, wsdl, sts-securitytokenservice

I am new to python development and still learning it so my question can be little naive please bear with it :)

Is it possible to build Security Token Service (STS) using python following wsdk and soap ? if yes how ? I have checked here [STS using Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli) but not sure how to use it! and how it will work

Is there any other ready made solution that I can customized